# reCaptcha - "send alerts to owners" - who?

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to get reCaptcha working on my website.
I found out I have to register my domain for this first, since I already have a google account this is quite easy, but the very last checkbox made me think:
[image: Send alerts to owners]
How does google determine who the `owners` are?
And what kind of alerts will those be? E-Mails?

I'm a bit worried that some random person will get an E-Mail one day not knowing what to do with it since I'm not the only one working on that domain. And if they just mean my google account I'm registering this with...that doesn't make sense because they should've written "you" instead of `owners` then. - although `your site` is making this even more confusing. :D

I'm aware this is not directly a programming question.
I'm open for suggestions for a better Stack-exchange platform to ask this question at, there are too many - I couldn't find any other that seem to fit.

Answer (score 1):

In the reCAPTCHA admin settings, there is a textbox where you can enter a list of email addresses for owners.  This will grant them access to manage the reCAPTCHA settings and send them alerts, if enabled.

[image: reCAPTCHA admin settings]